# calling a built in function after shadowing

Tags: python

How can I call a built-in function after I have defined another one with the same name? For instance:

```
def eval(e):
  ...

eval('print(1)') # I'd like to call the built-in one rather than my own eval
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have shadowed it in the first place?

Comment: `import builtins; builtins.eval()` But I also would just not shadow it in the first place.

Comment: Can you give an example of a scenario you actually need this functionality? out of curiosity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__builtins__`:

```py
>>> eval = 'foo' # shadowed
>>> __builtins__.eval('1 + 1')
2
```

But of course, it's better to just not shadow built-in names.